# One user of exchange unable to send external e-mails

Tags: email, exchange-2007

We have one individual user on exchange that is unable to send external email, such as to gmail, Hotmail, etc.  This user can receive external e-mail, and send/receive email to local users.  There are no errors or bounce back messages, tracking the sender on exchange shows "event id" as FAIL and "source" as AGENT but not much if any other information.

Is there a way to set up logging to see what the heck this "agent" is that the event FAIL occurs on?

Answer (score -2):

Found an error in transport rules.